# How to use functions glfwPollEvents and glfwWaitEvents simultaneously?

Tags: multithreading, events, glfw

So basically, **glfwPollEvents** used for real-time graphics engines when rendering some neat models or scenes.
**glfwWaitEvents** on other hands used for UI and turn-based applications, when there is no need in continuous rendering *(Redrawing only when needed)*
I have my **custom editor**, and **scene viewport** in my **engine**. I want to split them in such way that editor will be updated when it needed(using glfwWaitEvents). But for scene viewport I want using glfwPollEvent(because continuous rendering). So how can I accomplish this?

I cannot use them in one thread, because **glfwWaitEvents** will block main thread(and **glfwPollEvents** will be blocked too), until some event accure.
Also I've tried use **multithreading** solution, but as I know, all OpenGL draw calls has to be done from **single thread**.
For now, my solution is that I am using **glfwWaitEvents**, and when some Redrawing needed to be done, my engine call **glfwEmptyEvent** *(for awakening my blocked thread)*. So what's the best way?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the problem, but wouldn't a simple `if (editorMode) { glfwWaitEvents(); } else { glfwPollEvents(); }` do the job?

Comment: Sorry, but no. One window, just different viewports.

Comment: *all OpenGL draw calls has to be done from single thread*: This is not entirely true: OpenGL calls have to be made from the thread in which the OpenGL context is made current. A context may be current in exactly one thread and each thread may only have one context current. It is perfectly fine though to have different threads with different OpenGL context.

Comment: But your problem is actually less about the OpenGL commands, but about the glfw calls. Could you show how you initialize the multiple viewports in your engine? Are they separate windows? Are they separate controls in the same window? Or a single OpenGL window where you decide with `glViewport` where to render to?

Comment: How about: [glfwWaitEventsTimeout](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga605a178db92f1a7f1a925563ef3ea2cf). This combines continuous rendering at a certain frequency **and** listening for occurring events.